# Create different objects by parsed text

Tags: python, text, dynamic, parameters, init

1.
There is parsed text that contains shape information.
3 different shapes are possible: Circle, rectangle, triangle.

The parsed parameter have the following form:

```
['circle', [['id', '11'], ['color', 11403055], ['x', '10'], ['y', '10'], ['radius', '20']]]
['rectangle', [['id', '2'], ['color', 10494192], ['x', '10'], ['y', '20'], ['width', '10'], ['height', '10']]]
['triangle', [['id', '7'], ['color', 16716947], ['ax', '50'], ['ay', '15'], ['bx', '15'], ['by','40'], ['cx', '100'], ['cy', '100']]]
```

2.
The 3 shape classes inherit from baseclass 'Shape':

```
class Shape(object):
    def __init__ (self, id, color, x, y):
        self.__id = id
        self.__color = color
        self.__p = g.Point2d(x, y)
 class Circle(Shape):
    def __init__ (self, id, color, x, y, radius):
        self.__type = "circle"
        self.__radius = radius
        super(Circle, self).__init__(id, color, x, y)

class Rectangle(Shape):
    def __init__ (self, id, color, x, y, width, height):
        self.__type = "rectangle"
        self.__dim = g.Point2d(width, height)
        super(Rectangle, self).__init__(id, color, x, y)

class Triangle(Shape):
    def __init__ (self, id, color, x, y, bx, by, cx, cy):
        self.__type = "triangle"
        self.__b = g.Point2d(bx, by)
        self.__c = g.Point2d(cx, cy)
        super(Triangle, self).__init__(id, color, x, y)
```

3.
My question is how to create shapes from the parsed text?
How can I call the right constructor and how to pass the right parameter list? I want to impmement the link of parsed parameter and shape classes in that way: If the program should handle a new shape (e.g. Polygon), I just want to create a new class 'Polygon'.
(e.g. `['polygon', [['id', '151'], ['color', 11403055], ['x', '10'], ['y', '10'], ['corners', '7']]]`)
What is the pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

- for each param `list` extract the class name, and get the real class using a dictionary (else, it would require evaluating the capitalized name, not very pythonic)
- get the parameter name/value tuples, and build a dictionary out of it
- create your class instance by querying the class object from the `name2class` dictionary and pass the parameters using `**` notation

code:

```
param_list = [    ['circle', [['id', '11'], ['color', 11403055], ['x', '10'], ['y', '10'], ['radius', '20']]],
    ['rectangle', [['id', '2'], ['color', 10494192], ['x', '10'], ['y', '20'], ['width', '10'], ['height', '10']]],
    ['triangle', [['id', '7'], ['color', 16716947], ['ax', '50'], ['ay', '15'], ['bx', '15'], ['by','40'], ['cx', '100'], ['cy', '100']]]]

name2class = {'circle':Circle, 'rectangle':Rectangle, 'triangle':Triangle}

for param in param_list:
    class_params = dict(param[1])  # dict from param tuples
    class_name = param[0]
    o = name2class[class_name](**class_params)
```

note that it currently chokes when building `Triangle` because you're missing 2 parameters `ax` and `ay`.
The parameters from the list must match the `__init__` parameters exactly or you'll get an error (explicit, at least)

To avoid using `name2class` dictionary you could do:

```
class_name = param[0].capitalize()
o = eval(class_name)(**class_params)
```

although usage of `eval` is usually overkill and has severe security issues. You've been warned.

Comment: your solution works fine after renamed 2 parameter in contructor of Triangle!